# Reservar memoria en array de strings en c

Tags: c

Buenas tardes, quiero crear en c un array de cadenas, donde cada cadena tenga 1024 caracteres, para ello tengo una variable N donde me dice el número de cadenas que tengo, lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

```
char *frases[1024] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * N);
```

Pero esto me esta dando errores.

Answer (score 6):

Lo estás haciendo al revés.

```
char *frases[1024]
```

quiere decir

> un arreglo de 1024 elementos, cada uno de los cuales es un puntero a `char`.

Para casos así, utilizo un *truco* muy simple: una `struct` auxiliar:

```
struct frase_t {
  char texto[1024];
};
```

Con lo que declarar un *arreglo* de punteros del tamaño que queramos es muy simple, y encuentro que mas fácil de entender:

```
struct frase_t *frases[N];
```

Ahora, para usar `malloc( )`, hay que tener en cuenta que cada elemento del *arreglo* ha de ser asignado de forma individual:

```
struct frase_t {
  char texto[1024];
};

struct frase_t *frases[N];

for( int idx = 0; idx < N; ++idx ) {
  frases[idx] = (struct frase_t *)malloc( sizeof( struct frase_t ) );
}
```

Y listo, un *arreglo* de `N` punteros, cada uno de ellos apunta a una `struct frase_t`, la cual tiene exactamente `1024` `char`.

Para acceder a una *frase* cualquier, podemos hacer

```
( frases[5] )->texto
```

o incluso

```
(char *)( frases[5] );
```

Ya que en C, el primero elemento de una `struct` **está garantizado** que comienza en la misma posición de memoria que la propia `struct`.