# no logro imprimir el nombre completo ni la direccion si estan son muy largas

Tags: c

este es mi codigo, si capturo un nombre largo por ejemplo, erick jesus mendoza sedas, y una direccion larga por ejemplo, convento de dominicos 91-a, me encima los valores al imprimir, incluso no me deja capturar los datos integ y sangre, adjunto captura del resultado

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct estructura 
{   /* Definimos la estructura */
 char nombre[5], dir[10], sangre[2];
 int edad, integ;
};

struct estructura bene; /* Declaramos la variable bene con esa estructura */

main()
{
printf( "Escribe tu nombre: " );
scanf( "%s", &bene.nombre );
system("cls");
printf( "Escribe tu edad: " );
fflush( stdin );
scanf( "%d", &bene.edad );
system("cls");
printf( "Escribe tu direccion: " );
scanf( "%s", &bene.dir );
system("cls");
printf( "Escribe el numero de personas de tu familia: " );
scanf( "%d", &bene.integ );
system("cls");
printf( "Escribe tu tipo de sangre: " );
scanf( "%s", &bene.sangre );
system("cls");
printf( "Tus datos registrados son: \n\n"); 
printf( "  Nombre: %s \n", bene.nombre);
printf( "  Edad: %d \n", bene.edad );
printf( "  Direccion: %s \n", bene.dir );
printf( "  Integrantes: %d \n", bene.integ );
printf( "  Tipo de sangre: %s \n", bene.sangre );

return 0;
}
```

[image: nombre]
[image: direccion]
[image: resultado]

Comment: reserva mas memoria: cambia `nombre[5]` a `nombre[100]`

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/125459/120826

Answer (score 1):

Podrías tratar de sustituir el `scanf("",& n)` por un `gets(n)`

El scanf solo te lee la primera cadena de texto hasta un espacio o un fin de linea, gets te lee todo el texto.

Ademas de incrementar tu limite de caracteres en tu estructura:

```
 char nombre[5], dir[10], sangre[2];
```

A

```
 char nombre[30], dir[30], sangre[2];
```

que con el actual solo permites que 5 y 10 caracteres se contabilicen respectivamente.

Comment: Si cambias `gets` for `fgets` estás más seguro :)